# Using S3 object in S4 generic method causes error

Tags: r, r-s4

This is an example from [Hadley's advanced R book:](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html)

```
setGeneric("type", function(x) standardGeneric("type"))
setMethod("type", signature("matrix"), function(x) "matrix")
setMethod("type", signature("character"), function(x) "character")

type(letters)
type(matrix(letters, ncol = 2))

foo <- structure(list(x = 1), class = "foo")
type(foo)

setOldClass("foo")
setMethod("type", signature("foo"), function(x) "foo")

type(foo)

setMethod("+", signature(e1 = "foo", e2 = "numeric"), function(e1, e2) {
  structure(list(x = e1$x + e2), class = "foo")
})
foo + 3
```

Everything works as expected except for the last line, which brings up an error in R 3.1.3:

```
Error in foo + 3 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I can confirm the error. I can't say exactly why this does not work, but at least you can get the desired behaviour by defining `\`+.foo\` <- function(e1, e2) {structure(list(x = e1$x + e2), class = "foo")}`, and now `foo + 3` will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by confusion between S3 and S4 class systems. `foo` is an S3 class (it's created with `setOldClass` rather than `setClass`), so when `+` is called with it as first argument it tries S3 method dispatch (looking for a function called `+.foo`). This is why the suggestion in comments about defining such a function solves the problem.

if `foo` were a "pure S4" class (i.e. it has slots and is created via `setClass`) then your code would work.